# Why are the Jesuits and Society of the Sacred Heart gender specific?

Tags: catholicism, society-of-sacred-heart

Why is it impossible for women to join the Jesuit order but must instead join Society of the Sacred Heart?  Is there something in the initiation ritual that would exclude women?

Comment: I wonder if this oath is true: http://www.ianpaisley.org/article.asp?ArtKey=jesuit

Comment: Probably tradition.

Comment: And why wouldn't they let me play on the girls basketball team in high school?  Because it was a girls basketball team!

Comment: It is funny when other very similar groups get criticized for the same thing.  But it's all good if it is the Jesuits.

Comment: Who's unfairly giving the Jesuits a "free pass" that you're referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Society of Jesus and the Society of the Sacred Heart are both religious orders. All Catholic religious orders are by definition either for men or for women.

As to *why* this is... Well, historical Catholic understanding gave very different roles to men and women both in normal life and in the sphere of religion. Men, for instance, had priestly roles, preaching roles, roles teaching in universities and the like. Women, by contrast, had roles that mainly consisted of charitable works and, in recent centuries, the education of girls. They were distinctly different roles, and therefore had entirely different orders.